# In Kubernetes, Is there any difference between localhost and own FQDN?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, tcp, apache-zookeeper

I want to set a liveness-probe for my zookeeper statefulset as follows:

```
exec [/bin/bash -c OK=$(echo ruok | nc localhost 2181); if [[ $OK = imok ]]; then exit 0; fi; exit 1;]
```

but liveness-probe keeps failing with an error.

```
Ncat: Cannot assign requested address.
```

If I change a hostname to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0, I get another error.

```
Ncat: Connection refused
```

I get the same error even when I execute a ncat in the pod directly by 'kubectl exec'.

but If I change a hostname to pod's headless-service FQDN, everything works fine.

I cannot understand why I get different results even I connect to the same host.
Whats's the difference between connecting to localhost or own FQDN?

(zookeeper server list is consists of FQDN of pods.)

Comment: How did you provision your cluster? Did you add entries to pod /etc/hosts? Which zookeper image are you using? I have no problems after deploying zookeeper with [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/#creating-a-zookeeper-ensemble)